# What laminate to I use for interior of kitchen cabinets?

Tags: cabinets, laminate, melamine

I have a void left after removing an appliance that is not being replaced. Due to the size I'll be building my own cabinet. To match the interior of the existing cabinets I need a matte white laminate, but I am unclear what type of type. All my searches show countertop laminate, or resurfacing laminate meant for the exterior.

To achieve the look and feel for the interior of a standard laminated cabinet, what type of laminate would work best to be placed of 1/2" particle board?

Comment: Take a photo of the existing cabinet and ask the lumber supplier or the cabinet builder. Good luck on both counts.

Comment: It might be easier to buy laminated boards, they are very easy to find in hardware stores, and easier to cut them to size and attach them to the adjacent cabinets than to laminate old particle board that is probably slightly swollen from moisture in the kitchen.  Even easier, If the space was for an appliance you'll probably find that a standard-sized cabinet will fit in nicely with a small gap-fill panel.